# Jdbc data type to Spark SQL datatype

Tags: scala, jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Need to write a method that will take in list of column names & list of column types (JDBC) & return a `StructType` which will be used to create a DataFrame.

I know I can write a method with a bunch of `case` statements to convert JDBC column type to appropriate DataType (such as StringType, IntegerType etc), but wondering if such a method already exists.

There’s a `DataType.fromJson` method, but I don’t know/understand the structure of the JSON I need to pass to it.

Example input:

List of column names:  UserName, Age, Salary
List of column types: java.lang.String, java.lang.Long, java.lang.Double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to JDBC source with a table having a given schema you can simply copy from there:

```
val jdbcOptions: Map[String, String] = ???
val jdbcSchema = sqlContext.load("jdbc", jdbcOptions).schema
```

JSON representation is quite simple. Each `StructField` is represented as document with fields `metadata`, `name`, `nullable` and `type`.

```
{"metadata":{},"name":"f","nullable":true,"type":"string"}
```

For most applications you can ignore `metadata` and focus on the remaining three. Tricky part is mapping from Java class to `type`, but a naive solution can look like this:

```
import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._
import net.liftweb.json.{compact, render}

val columns = Seq(
    ("UserName", "java.lang.String"),
    ("Age", "java.lang.Long"),
    ("Salary", "java.lang.Double")
).map{case (n, t) => (n, t.split("\\.").last.toLowerCase)}

val fields =  columns.map {case (n, t) => (
    ("metadata" -> Map.empty[String, String]) ~
    ("name" -> n) ~
    ("nullable" -> false) ~
    ("type" -> t)
)}

val schemaJSON = compact(render(("fields" -> fields) ~ ("type" -> "struct"))
val schema = DataType.fromJson(schemaJSON).asInstanceOf[StructType]
```